# Maximum Depth of Binary Tree: Why do the variables have to be declared locally?

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

When I try submitting code where the `ldepth` and `rdepth` variables are declared before the `if-else` block, the code gives incorrect solutions for test cases.

I understand and was able to submit a working recursive solution where the `ldepth` and `rdepth` variables are declared locally inside the else statement.

Why do these variables have to be declared inside the `if-else` block?

This is my incorrect solution:

```java
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public int maxDepth(TreeNode root) {
        int depth;
        int rdepth;
        int ldepth;
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
             ldepth = maxDepth(root.left);
             rdepth = maxDepth(root.right);

            if (ldepth > rdepth) {
                depth = ldepth + 1;
                return depth;
            }

            if (rdepth > ldepth) {
                depth = rdepth + 1;
                return depth;
            }

            else {
                depth = rdepth + 1;
                return depth;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a test case where the two answers differ?

Comment: To make your code [mcve]  please hard code test data. Side note: there is no need for explicit `else{}` after `if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }`. The `else{}` makes no difference in this case.